# Очень медленно работает программа на python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Всем привет, написал скрипт(парсер интернет магазина), запускаю в консоли, все работает весьма резво. Решил придать какой-то внешний вид программе, сделал два TextInput'а и две кнопки. Запускаю - окно зависает, хотя в консоль все выдается,
как и прежде лихо. Прочитал, что если скомпилировать в .exe файл, то все заработает, но нет, так же виснет. Кто знает, как ускорить процесс, буду признателен.

Comment: Управление передаётся от интерфейса вашей программе, и пока программа не вернёт управление интерфейсу, интерфейс будет зависший — всё в порядке. Решение — запускать интерфейс в отдельном потоке (читайте про потоки и их дружбу с вашим модулем для интерфейсов в интернете)

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: Почитайте про модуль threading. Это про многопоточность. Товарищ сверху все правильно написал. Просто парсинг медленно выполняется и программа подвисает.

Comment: Как раз сегодня все удалось и именно с модулем threading. Спасибо за комментарий